# Get string of the keyboard key

Tags: java, swing, keyboard

Is there any way to get the String text representation of a keyboard key? 
Examples:

```
Input: User presses Shift
Output: "Shift"

Input: User presses F1
Output: "F1"

Input: User presses Left arrow key
Output: "Left Arrow"
```

Im using a keylistener in order to get the key strokes by the way

Comment: create a hash map of key values and corresponding string value and get the value on every key press

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closest to this is KeyEvent.getKeyText: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyText(int)

I say closest to because there are some platform-specific differences in implementation on certain keys

Comment: F.Y.I. - form javaDoc -
Key combinations which do not result in Unicode characters, such as action keys like F1 and the HELP key, do not generate KEY_TYPED events